# Django Count() multiple fields and sort by their sum

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a model named `Topiccenter`. and there are many entries in each Topiccenter.

```
class Topiccenter(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()

class Book(models.Model):
  tc = models.ForeignKey(Topiccenter,related_name="tc_book_entries")
  name = models.TextField()

class Journal(models.Model):
  tc = models.ForeignKey(Topiccenter,related_name="tc_journal_entries")
  name = models.TextField()
```

I want to get topiccenters and sort them by `max entries` and `min entries`.

I tried

```
Topiccenter.objects.annotate(sum_entries=Sum('tc_book_entries','tc_journal_entries')).order_by('-sum_entries')
```

but this is not working

Comment: what's the inherent difference between Journal and Book that requires them to each have its own table?

Comment: @yuvi, actually there are more fields, i just posted a simplified version. there are reasons why should exist separately

Comment: Alright. Because the most natural solution would've been to merge them and use a third field to decide if it's a book or journal (it would also be more efficient)

Comment: @yuvi you are right. thanks for hint :)

Comment: So should I post this as an optional answer? Or is @Bibhas answer is what you're looking for?

Comment: @yuvi, i think Bibhas has mentioned the right way of querying. honestly, i dont want to change my db structure since it has a lot of data already in it on production :(

Comment: Sure thing. That's quite understandable. If you ever face some problems with efficiency though, consider a migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
Topiccenter.objects.annotate(
    sum_books=Sum('tc_book_entries'),
    sum_journals=Sum('tc_journal_entries')
).extra({
    'select': {
        'sum_entries': 'sum_books + sum_journals'
    }
}).order_by('-sum_entries')
```

This should work.